# Mysql set default to null if multiple rows dont match

Tags: mysql, select, setdefault

I have a table called invoices.  to help make this question simple we will say that there are 4 columns in the invoice.

```
id                    (PK auto int)
booking_id            (int)
is_business_invoice   (1 or 0 or NULL)
amount                (decimal)
```

A booking can have multiple invoices.

Im tryng to write a query what will determine if for a given booking id they are all business invoices or personal invoices.  Where there are multiple invoices of different `is_business_invoice` types it will default to null.  If there are 3 bookings and all 3 are `is_business_invoice` then it will return 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select case when count(is_business_invoice) = sum(is_business_invoice) 
            then 1 
            when sum(is_business_invoice) = 0
            then 0
            else null 
      end as IsBusinessInvoices
from invoices
group by booking_id
```